# How to make horizontally flipped images look good in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7, right-to-left

I'm working on a project that supports many different languages. We are currently adding Hebrew, which is a right-to-left language. Because of this, a lot of our layout has to be mirrored. I created a script that will do a lot of this automatically, but images have to be mirrored as well. We have a class called `.rtl` which will flip whatever is in it horizontally (normally only applied to images). The class is as follows:

```
.rtl {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

This correctly flips images cross-browser, but it seems that IE<10 has very bad rendering artifacts. Is there a way to remedy this? The only alternative is to keep a mirrored png file for every image in our project (which is a lot), so this isn't a very a very feasible solution. I have attached an image showing the issue with IE7 on top and Chrome (which looks correct) on the bottom. In normal languages, the text is on the left and the picture is on the right, but in right-to-left languages this had to be flipped, thus the arrow had to be flipped, and also the "glow" effect on the text as well.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to apply parantheses to your filter like so: `filter:fliph()`.
The second approach you could try is the syntax of IE5.5-9 that would look like this: `filter: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2, mirror=1)` like [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx) recommends.
If this doesn't help, you should try [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/).